# Alien on the run, Alien Cop chasing

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie way back in the 80s and can't find a name to it. From what I remember, it has the following:

- Alien on the run on Earth
- Alien cop chasing him
- Alien cop reveals himself/is caught by human police after being wounded and declaring "I'm a cop, like you"
- Human cop decides to help out
- Alien on the run attacks people by injecting a liquid into them, and sucking out a sample of their blood with a tube/needle arrangement - can't remember why though, and I think he injects this sample into the next human and so forth
- Most victims are male and I think one was female.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are flying metal discs also involved? Because it sounds like *I Come In Peace* (AKA [Dark Angel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099817/combined)) with Dolph Lundgren from 1990. From the Wiki recap:

> **[Alien] Talec shoots his victims full of drugs** and then uses alien technology to extract endorphins from their brains, synthesizing them into a substance to be used by addicts on his home planet. **He is pursued by an alien cop named Azeck, who warns [cop] Caine** and [FBI agent] Smith that if Talec is not stopped, thousands of intergalactic drug dealers will start to come to Earth to slaughter its population. Putting aside their differences, Smith and Caine team up to take Talec down.

That tube\needle thing shoots out of the bad alien's hand. [The trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVu4XatjAFw) is currently available on Youtube and so is [the full movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsNj2tkZJAc) - and in 1:01:15, the wounded alien cop reveals himself to the hero and tells him that he's **"an officer of the law, like you"**.

Comment: BTW, when I started reading the question, I first thought of [The Hidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_%28film%29). I quickly realized it's not it, but you should check it out anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up two movies and I understand it since these two movies sort of go together in my mind - plus the titles have similarities. I Come In Peace has been mentioned, but the beginning of your description more closely matches Peacemaker - a 1990 film with Robert Forster as the alien policeman. I always remember the part at the medical examiner where one of the earth cops says he wants to watch the autopsy to see if there is an "S" on the guy's chest.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like *[The Hidden](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/)*:

> An alien parasite with the ability to possess human bodies goes on a violent crime spree in LA, pursued by a human cop and an alien cop inhabiting a human body.